# Calculate rotation between two Vector2s around a pivot

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, xna-4.0

[image]Hello all.

After a good long Sunday google I am going to have to hang my head in shame and ask the question...

What I have is a pivot vector2, a "Previous" vector2 and a "Current" vector2.

I would like to be able to calculate the rotation in radians between them. A slight complication is the fact that the pivot may moved between previous and current but ill deal with the offsetting as a separate issue if you don't have the time to bring that into the fold.

To clarify, an object which has two vectors, a pivot and a base ... the pivot sitting in the centre and the base at the bottom is rotated around an external pivot. I need to work out the rotation of the object itself around its centre using the two mentioned vectors.

Very big thanks to anyone that can help.

**Background to problem**

I have a game where an object is rotated around an external pivot. By using using two points (one in the centre, one at the base of the object) I am wanting to to work out the rotation that needs to be applied to the objects sprite around its centre to conform to the larger rotation that has been applied.

Comment: Not really sure how master pivot comes into this. Do you want the angle between obj.cur.base -> master -> obj.prev.base? Or the angle difference between obj.cur.pivot->obj.cur.base and obj.prev.pivot -> obj.prev.base? Either way, the cross product is the way to go, and it sounds like with that info you should be able to work out the details.

Comment: Yea I am just playing with it now, appologies I think I made the situation more complicated by attempting to make it more clear. The master pivot is simply the reason the object has moved and rotated. i.e. the object has been rotated around the master pivot, so now i need to see how much the object has rotated around its centre because of that rotation. I think I have enough to be working with now though with luck. Cheers both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Product) of the differences between the vectors and the pivot:

```
Vector2 a = Pivot - Previous, b = Current - pivot;
double angle = a.X * b.Y - a.Y * b.X;
```

Comment: +1, but you must remember to "unit" the source vectors, or divide the resulting "angle" by "length(a) * length(b)".